# Arduino, Particle, Teensy debugging?

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm starting to use Visual Studio Code for my IoT work, including microprocessor coding. I've used Arduino and Teensy, my current project is using a Particle Electron.
I need a head start finding the correct add-ins and/or approach to debug an Electron. I believe my 2 unknowns are:

- What VSCode extension should I use, does one exist, do I need one?
- Do I require a piece of hardware, like the Particle debug shield, ST-Link J-Link, etc.?

Is there a common interface/protocol I should be looking for, to
   measure VSCode compatibility for debuggers, etc.?

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer to your query [here](https://docs.particle.io/reference/cli/#particle-compile) :

Spend some time reading its documentation.

compiling details can be found [here](https://docs.particle.io/reference/cli/#compiling-a-project).

Comment: Thanks for the info Billa, however my question is regarding debugging, not compiling. I have the Electron code compiling and flashing just fine with VSCore, now I need to debug.